# Problem with chaset encoding using ORACLE utl_smtp

Tags: oracle, plsql, character-encoding

I'm working with Oracle 12.2.0.1.0.
We have created a procedure that sends email with UTL_SMTP package.
Evrything works fine but we lost encoding specific for polish language.

NLS settings:
NLS_CHARACTERSET = EE8MSWIN1250;
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16;

We keep msg text in CLOB column in table.

```
...
mime_type  IN VARCHAR2  DEFAULT 'text/plain',
message IN CLOB,
...
conn utl_smtp.connection;
...
    conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(mail_host, mail_port);
    utl_smtp.helo(conn, mail_host);
...
    utl_smtp.mail(conn, get_address(my_sender));
    utl_smtp.rcpt(conn, get_address(my_recipients));

    utl_smtp.open_data(conn);
    write_mime_header(conn, 'From', sender);
    write_mime_header(conn, 'To', recipients);
    write_mime_header(conn, 'Subject', subject);
    write_mime_header(conn, 'Content-Type', mime_type);
...
    loop
       exit when offset > dbms_lob.getlength(message);
       utl_smtp.write_data(conn, dbms_lob.substr( message, 255, offset ));
       offset := offset + 255;
    end loop;
...
    utl_smtp.close_data(conn);
    utl_smtp.quit(conn);
...
```

Code for write_mime_header

```
  PROCEDURE write_mime_header(conn  IN OUT NOCOPY utl_smtp.connection,
                  name  IN VARCHAR2,
                  value IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    utl_smtp.write_data(conn, name || ': ' || value || utl_tcp.CRLF);
  END;
```

Unfortunately we lose the char encoding. ex. "użytkownik" in clob "uzytkownik" in mail.

I tried to set the charset in content-type but we still have a problem.

```
    write_mime_header(conn, 'Content-Type','text/plain; charset="UTF8"');
    utl_smtp.write_data(conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="EE8MSWIN1250"' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
```

How to set the encoding of mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_SMTP.html#GUID-E9866416-3DD3-4915-9198-999ADFACBFFA):

> **Usage Notes**
> ...
>
> - Text (`VARCHAR2`) data sent using `WRITE_DATA` is converted to US7ASCII before it is sent. If the text contains multibyte characters, each multibyte character in the text that cannot be converted to US7ASCII is replaced by a '?' character. If 8BITMIME extension is negotiated with the SMTP server using the `EHLO` subprogram, multibyte `VARCHAR2` data can be sent by first converting the text to `RAW` using the `UTL_RAW` package, and then sending the `RAW` data using `WRITE_RAW_DATA`.

So you can change from `HELO` to `EHLO` and see if that is supported; and then use something like:

```
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_lob.substr(message, 255, offset)));
```

Otherwise you would need to base64-encode the message.

Comment: This  helps a little. Now some of specific chars are displaying properly but some of them are š,

Comment: I don't know if your Content-Type setting are right now. EE8MSWIN1250 is an Oracle value so that should maybe be 'WIndows-1250' there? And MIME shoudl be the same, perhaps? Not sure, sorry...

Comment: Yes, you are right. With charset=windows-1250 everything works fine :)